# Checking damaged resistance

Tags: resistance, damage

I have a battery charger on which a resistor is damaged and I don't know how much resistance was that.
Is there any way to check damaged resistor's value?
And also please let know that if a resistor has "100" written on it what does it means?

[image]

Comment: Are you implying that electronics engineers are not normal? How about a photo of what you are talking about. Welcome, but please use proper capitalization 'I', not 'i' and grammar.

Comment: I am Mechanical Engineer and I have edited my question please check if you can understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Much better, thanks). The resistor marked 100 in this case is 10 ohms.

The left two digits are the value (10) and the right hand digit is the multiplier (10^0 = 1)

A resistor marked 101 would be 100 ohms.

Unfortunately it's not possible to tell what the burned up resistor was, and it's quite likely that simply replacing it won't fix it (something else has gone wrong, most likely).

If there was a repetitive pattern in the charger (one section for each cell) it might be possible to look at undamaged sections and find the value.

Comment: Question on your first answer that i checked the 100 resistance with miltimeter it shows 3 ohms on meter what is logic in it, and 2ndly yes the capacitor is damaged but if i replace the capacitor i have to replace the resistance too and for that i don't know how much it is i think you can see printed circuit in picture and can understand better than me so do you think both resistances are equal?

Comment: In circuit the resistance measurement may be lower because of other circuit elements in parallel. I have no reason to think those parts would be equal value, sorry.